# Converting X509Certificate2 certificate into BouncyCastle X509Certificate

Tags: c#

I have an object of System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.
I need to convert it into an object of Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's been a while since I played with Bouncy Castle.  Basically take X509Certificate2.RawData and pass it to the BC X509Certificate constructor.

If I remember correctly, BC has a `Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities`.  This should allow you to import a certificate.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I want to play with Bouncy Castle too :P. but no documentation has made my life harder here. Can you share some experience or some links from where I can learn a bit of it...

also, can I browse local keystore, using BC

Comment: Yeah BC .Net is poorly documented, but it has every crypto function you want.  I learnt it by reading the source code, especially the unit tests.  Good luck.

Answer (score 28):

Use `Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate`, which takes a `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate` and returns a `Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate`.

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly. The FromX509Certificate also takes a System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 object as  X509Certificate2 derives from X509Certificate (adding this for newbies like myself)

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I do that (BouncyCastle.Crypto version 1.8.1.0):

```
var cert = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser()
    .ReadCertificate(x509Certificate2.GetRawCertData());
```

In other answers mentioned `Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(X509Certificate)` works too.